# Why does "strcat" on an array cause overwriting?

Tags: c, strcat

```
strcat(argv[1], ".txt");
puts(argv[1]);
strcat(argv[2], ".txt");
puts(argv[2]);
puts(argv[1]);
```

Say the first([1]) argument is called "a" and the second([2]) "b". This code gives the following output: 
`a.txt`
    `txt.txt`
    `a.txt.txt`

Why is this happening?? It seems as if the strcat starts overwriting arg[2]?

Comment: "string management" in C is different.

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to make any assumptions about amount of memory allocated to store strings pointed by `argv[i]`. In particular, you are not allowed to assume that you can expand these strings by `strcat`-ing anything to them. Doing so will generally lead to undefined behavior. This is exactly what you observed in your experiment.

While it is legal to modify the strings pointed by `argv[i]` without changing their length, it is not generally possible to "expand" them in place. It is conceivable that these strings might immediately follow each other in memory, meaning that writing anything past the end of string pointed by `argv[1]` would overwrite string pointed by `argv[2]` and so on.

Comment: I see, so how would I append the .txt ending?

Comment: @Hedhed make another string. Allocate enough bytes with (malloc)

Comment: @Hedhed: What is your intended effect of appending `.txt` directly to string stored at memory location pointed by `argv[1]`  instead of making a completely independent string?